# Where can I find a history/log of the featured questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers, questions, bounty

If I've understood this correctly, then all the ["bounty" questions](https://ux.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty) are listed in the ["featured" section](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=featured).  Right?

But once the bounty is awarded, then they disappear from that list.

Since many of these questions are pretty interesting, and particularly since many of the answers are very good, I would often like to have a second look at these questions *after* the bounty period is over.

**Where can I find "recently awarded bounties" or "recently bountied questions"?**

Answer (score 1):

Not without using the Data Explorer to query the Stack Exchange data; there's no in-site list at the moment. There's a premade query you can run, [Top 200 bounties by bounty amount](http://data.stackexchange.com/user%20experience/query/62083/top-200-bounties-by-bounty-amount) which currently shows all past bounties for UX

Comment: Cool.  Haven't looked at SE.DataExplorer before...